# Can't run Karma with Angular 1.4.9 with error angular.module(...).info is not a function

Tags: angularjs, testing, karma-jasmine

When running `karma start --single-run`

there is an error

```
 Chrome 62.0.3202 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught TypeError: angular.module(...).info is not a function
  at /home/ali/bedopedia/client/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:80
```

When I opened anguler-mocks.js there is a function called info and it need angular 1.6 `.info({ angularVersion: '1.6.6' })`

here is package.json file

```
"devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.6.0",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-jsmeter": "^0.3.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.26",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.5.0"
  }
```

Comment: Why do you think that angular.module should have info as a function?

Comment: What versions of karma & angular are you using ?

Comment: edited, 
the info function is in file in node_modules so I don't know why it has function .info

Comment: So what angular version do you have? If 1.6 try to clear node_modules, set angular version to 1.6 explicity and run npm install again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by making angular-mocks version the same version of angular I am using.

make it `"angular-mocks": "1.4.9",` in package.json file

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck on that since 1h. Angular and angular-mocks (and @types/angular-mocks if using TypeScript) should have matching versions. In my case, the problem was a `^` on angular-mocks.