# "angular.module(...).info is not a function" despite all angular modules being the same version

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, angular-mock

I am trying to run Karma tests on my Angular project, but I am getting this error (through Chrome Headless):

```
Uncaught TypeError: angular.module(...).info is not a function at node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:806
```

This error occurred after updating from Node 6.4.0 to 10.6.0

Suggestions online (such as this: [Can't run Karma with Angular 1.4.9 with error angular.module(...).info is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47200345/cant-run-karma-with-angular-1-4-9-with-error-angular-module-info-is-not-a)) say to make sure angular and all its modules are on the same version. All of mine are on version 1.6.9, so that is not the problem.

What other possible problems could I be having?

Comment: I will close this issue. From doing some debugging, it seems that something else is somehow using an old version of angular (1.5.8) and the module `info` function was only added in 1.6.3, hence the error. This bug seems to be on my end so I will debug it myself. Thanks

Comment: For some reason, the angular version (1.5.8) in my npm cache was being used instead of the one in my node_modules. If anyone runs into this, try clearing your npm cache.